# Regex Help C# - At least 2 groups without spaces

Tags: .net, regex

I need help with regex in C#
I need to satisfy the following rules in a regex:

1. 8-28 characters without spaces and containing at least 2 of the following:
2. Uppercase Letters
3. Lowercase Letters
4. Numbers
5. Special Characters (!, @, #, $, %, ^ or *)

I tried the below regex. It is satisfying all the above rules expect for spaces. Please help

```
@"^(?=.\S*\d)(?=.\S*[A-Z]).{8,28}$|^(?=.\S*\d)(?=.\S*[a-z]).{8,28}$|^(?=.\S*[A-Z])(?=.\S*[!@#$%\^*]).{8,28}$|^(?=.\S*[a-z])(?=.\S*[!@#$%\^*]).{8,28}$|^(?=.\S*\d)(?=.\S*[!@#$%\^*]).{8,28}$|@"^(?=.\S*[A-Z])(?=.\S*[a-z]).{8,28}$";
```

Comment: When I see *at least N of the following* it means the regex is not the best approach here.

Comment: Could you give example of strings that matches and doesn't match?

Comment: Replace the `.\S*` with `\S*` and `.` with `\S`.